# I have installed Snow agent in Linux VM but status is not showing

Tags: linux

I have installed snow agent version 6.6.1 in Linux VM . I can see the version but however when I use `# systemctl status snow-agent` to see the status of whether it running or not, its not showing up. Can someone help and suggest on this. Thanks

```
[root@ause1qlnslfe01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep snow
snowagent-6.6.1-1689898818.x86_64

[root@ause1qlnslfe01 ~]# systemctl status snowagent
Unit snowagent.service could not be found.
[root@ause1qlnslfe01 ~]# systemctl status snow-agent
Unit snow-agent.service could not be found.
```

Comment: My reading of the snowagent documentation is that it is a scheduled scan needs to be put into cron. It is not a long-lived daemon. Have you configured anything like [this](https://docs.snowsoftware.com/snow-inventory/en/UUID-4157e250-2349-4ead-6aa8-d15deff1c486.html)?

Comment: Not sure, I am able to see version means snow agent got installed but when I am trying checking that whether it is running or not, it is not appearing that.